# NullPointerException Android Development Error

Tags: android

I am getting a NullPointerException on this line, if you could help me figure it out, that would be great!

```
double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusEditText.getText().toString());
```

Here is the entire code:

```
    public class areacircle extends Activity {
    TextView radiusTextView;
    TextView areaTextView;
    EditText radiusEditText;
    Button areaButton;
    EditText answerEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.areacircle);

         areaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.areaButton);
         answerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerEditText);
         radiusEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radiusEditText);


    }
    double pi = 3.14;
    double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusEditText.getText().toString());
    double finalRadius = radius * radius *pi;
    double area = Double.parseDouble(answerEditText.getText().toString());

    public void findarea(){

        answerEditText.setText(String.valueOf(finalRadius));


    }
}
```

areacircle.xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/radiusTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/acirclefirstnumbtn"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/radiusEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/radius"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/areaButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="findarea"
        android:text="@string/findarea"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/areaTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/area"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answerEditText"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/areatextview"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/areaanswer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would step through the code an made sure radiusEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radiusEditText); didn't end up being null

Comment: (off topic) `double pi = 3.14;` should use `Math.PI` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these lines:

```
double pi = 3.14;
double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusEditText.getText().toString());
double finalRadius = radius * radius *pi;
double area = Double.parseDouble(answerEditText.getText().toString());
```

really placed *outside* of any methods? If so, they will execute during the object constructor - i.e. *before* `onCreate()` is run. This means that `radiusEditText` hasn't been assigned yet and will explain your null pointer exception.

To solve, either put these inside `findarea()` (which is presumably called by some callback method) or into some other callback method, so they are run after `onCreate()`. For example:

```
// Calculate PI beforehand
final double pi = Math.PI;

public void findarea(){
    // Calculate the value of answerEditText
    double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusEditText.getText().toString());
    double finalRadius = radius * radius *pi;
    answerEditText.setText(String.valueOf(finalRadius));

    double area = Double.parseDouble(answerEditText.getText().toString());
    // do something with area?
}
```

Comment: Alex's answer looks neat. I also notice what you are doing inside findarea() though technically true, logically makes little sense. tip : use suitable method names for their appropriate actions.